# I cannot install Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I have burned the ISO image onto a disc, restarted my computer booting from the disc, gone through the "install ubuntu" option to run inside Windows 8. And a while later it tells me to remove the installation media, close the try and press enter.

Then it reboots my laptop, then takes me into Windows 8. Ubuntu literally did nothing!

I'm confused. And I'm stressed out. I've been at this for the pass 5 hours, FIVE hours!

I have a USB available if it's easier to install like that.

Answer (score 1):

I see these questions all the time.  Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows, while supported, is not as easy as the other two options:

- wipe windows and install Ubuntu
- keep windows and run Ubuntu in a Virtual machine.

If you're an Ubuntu first timer.  Download VirtualBox and install Ubuntu as a virutal machine.  Play with it, get used to it.  You may come to find out that you like it better than windows.

When you're ready to go "full Ubuntu", back up your data (music, pix, docs) from windows and then do a fresh clean install of Ubuntu.

*Note: While my answer won't help install Ubuntu alongside windows (which is very well documented), it does show two other options. I fully expect your down votes.*

Comment: Thank you. I may just give up and just install it over Windows 8. I hate Windows 8, been using it, gotten used to it, but I just want to go back to Windows 7, but then again, I want something new.